# merging diffs in two branches

Tags: svn

I have two branches from trunk that have been maintained separately over a year, say branch A and B. Now I am having to merge one into the other. What I want is to compare the changes in both and then whatever change is newer, that goes into the merged branch.

I have used SVN merge in the past, but the way I understood it is that it applies the 'diffs' in one branch to another. I don't want ALL the diffs - only that are newer.

Is it possible to do this in SVN?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Merge does a 3-way merge. That is a standard algorithm, that works like this:

- A most recent common ancestor, or base for short, revision is found. This is the revision just before the branch was created or the last revision that was merged from one version to the other.
- For each line that is the same in 'mine' (what you have checked out) as 'base', but differs in 'theirs' (the argument to merge), the line is used from 'theirs'.
- For each line that is the same in 'theirs' as 'base', local version is used (including the case it didn't change from base).
- For each line that is the same in 'mine' and 'theirs', that version is used, no matter what 'base' was.
- For each line that is different in all three of 'base', 'mine' and 'theirs', there is a conflict and you have to manually resolve it.

So this applies all changes from both branches. If the same change was done on both sides, than it's applied. If the same code was changed in different ways, it's conflict and you'll have to resolve it. And you won't see which particular revision it came from, they are all rolled up together.

Now if that's not what you want, the other option is to manually list the revisions to merge. That will only apply changes made in those particular revisions, each continuous range at a time (the algorithm is actually the same, but the base is the revision before start of the selected range). That means you have to hand-pick which changes you want. There are two issues with this approach: it will be a lot of work and you have to be careful to pick all changes required to make later ones work.

Now to your wanting all the "newer" changes. You have to define which ones that mean, in a way understandable by computer. And you have to be careful about the second problem above—the changes may depend on each other and you have to pick the depended-on changes too.